# ReactNative - SSLException Building Movies Example

Tags: java, android, node.js, android-ndk, react-native

I'm new to React Native and have been playing around with one or two examples. When I try and build the Android "Movies" Example on my **Mac** I get the following error:

```
./gradlew :Examples:Movies:android:app:installDebug

:ReactAndroid:downloadJSCHeaders FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':ReactAndroid:downloadJSCHeaders'.
javax.net.ssl.SSLException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not generate DH keypair
```

I've done npm install from the react-native directory that gets me this far and have the SDK and NDK locations set in my ./bash_profile. I've read elsewhere that my it could be something to do the the Android NDK version, I've tried using both **android-ndk-r10c** and **android-ndk-r11c**

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

If anyone is looking for the solution, you need to add this line to the buildscript dependencies in the `android/build.gradle` file

```
classpath 'de.undercouch:gradle-download-task:3.1.2'
```

Answer (score 0):

I eventually found a solution.
Instead of trying to compile the React Native example from inside the git cloned react-native directory I moved it into a completely fresh project e.g.

```
cd ~/Documents
react-native init Movies
```

Then copied the js files from the examples folder in the newly created one and ran in ios.

I'm not sure what the complication was but this resolved my issues.